# Hard drive with windows 8.1 installed not readable in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, usb

Today my system suddenly failed to start up and I have removed the hard disk of my faulty laptop and trying to read it on a windows 7 laptop. I plugged the hard drive on a usb 2.0 casing and plugged it via USB in a windows 7 laptop, unfortunately it gives a message that hard drive needs to be initialized and does not show the drive partitions. The hard drive had windows 8.1 installed on it on a zbook which had a UEFI system instead of BIOS. I am wondering if this may be the issue that windows 7 failed to recognize the drive of a newer system ? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Probably encrypted (Bitlocker) or a problem with the adapter you're using or the drive is defective.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - If the drive was encrypted by BitLocker Windows would have recognized it.  There is a simpler explanation, the HDD failed, which is the reason the laptop did not startup.

Comment: @Ahmed - There is no solution, the drive has failed, if the data must be recovered best send it to a data recovery company.  Most data recovery services consultations are actually free.  They only charge to recover the data, after they determine, data can be recovered.